# Bash script - "err: command not found"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script and I am using a for cycle to check my arguments.

```
for var in "$@"
do
    test_arg "$var"
done
```

And this is my test_arg function

```
function test_arg {
    [ -n "$1" ] || err "Empty argument"
    [ -f "$1" ] || err "Argument '$1' is not a file"
    [ -r "$1" ] || err "Data file '$1' is not readable"
    [ -s "$1" ] || err "Data file '$1' is empty"
    egrep -v '^-?([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$' "$1" && { echo "Bad data format in '$1'"; exit 1; }
}
```

However, when any of these conditions are not met, script only writes out "script.sh: line XX: err: command not found". I am not quite sure about the testing, I am a bash begginer.

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: `err "Empty argument"` -- `err` is not a built-in command, so unless you define it as a function, it won't be found.

Comment: By the way, don't use the `function` keyword; it serves no purpose but to make your code incompatible with baseline POSIX shells. Just `test_arg() { ...}` will do.

Comment: (...anyhow, this has nothing to do with `-s`, or with the `[` or `test` builtins).

Comment: If we are going to point out the `function` keyword (which I agree with Charles about), don't give `do` it's own line.  It serves no purpose but to make your code harder to read.

`for var in "$@"; do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code depends on a function named `err`. Consider defining it like so:

```
err() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }
```

Comment: yes - now it works like a charm - thank you very much sir - will accept as an answer when possible